# Inheriting properties of a class to another class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, queue, priority-queue

I created a class named `Queue`, which has some operations like insert, delete, search..etc.

Now I need to create another class named `PriorityQueue` that inherits properties of `Queue` class.
The new `PriorityQueue` class also needs a special property named `priority`.

How could I do it?

Comment: The answer lies in the question itself. `PriorityQueue` need to inherit from `Queue` (so use `extends`). And `priority` field is to be added to `PriorityQueue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extend your Queue class and add the attribute

```
public class PriorityQueue extends Queue {
    private final String priority; //assuming it's a string 
    public PriorityQueue(String priority) {
        super(); //call parent constructor 
        this.priority = priority;
    }
}
```